# Launch one activity from another

Tags: android, launching-application

i just want to know how can i detect if the user opens an app so an activity of mine launches as well.

For example, the user opens the sms app and right after a kind of lockscreen appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service which will run int the background and you can use [this API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29) to determine which activity is visible. That's how many app lock works.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I understand the Android system, it is not possible unless you are making a custom firmware.

Comment: This is wrong. There are multiple apps which do that on Google Play.

Comment: Can you please tell which apps are those? I don't think its a good idea for the system to open an app which the user doesn't intend to open.

Comment: Here is example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.smartlockfree&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS50aGlua3llYWguc21hcnRsb2NrZnJlZSJd

Comment: Generally speaking, I agree it's bad practice to open an application which user didn't intend to open. However, it can be done.

Comment: Ok I am sure that app uses a different API from the one you shared in your answer.

Comment: Those apps usually use that API or log reading. However, log reading got protected by permission on 4.1.